# Strip anything Outside first set of quotes in Javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I wan't to remove any character outside the first set of quotes in this string:

```
toastr.warning("Cynthia Open Chat and respond to request","",{"timeOut":5000,"progressBar":true,})
```

So that the result is `Cynthia G. Open Chat and respond to request`.

I was going with something like this `/\w.*(?="\w){1}/` but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Why not just create a function called `warning` in an object called `toastr`, and grab the first argument by `eval`ing it? Or is the source untrusted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easier to use `match`:

```
var str = 'toastr.warning("Cynthia Open Chat and respond to request","",{"timeOut":5000,"progressBar":true,})';

var repl = str.match(/"[^"]*/)[0].substring(1);
//=> Cynthia Open Chat and respond to request
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this `RegExp`:

```
var str = 'toastr.warning("Cynthia Open Chat and respond to request","",{"timeOut":5000,"progressBar":true,})';

var text = str.replace(/^[^"]*?"([^"]+)".*$/, "$1");
// Cynthia Open Chat and respond to request
```